# Is there a way to make Blazor allow outside http access?

Tags: http, blazor

I just got started with Blazor, following [Microsoft's Guide,](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/run) but I need to allow outside access from http, so I can access it from `<server-ip>:5000`, as I am running a linux VPS that I don't have GUI access to. Is there any way to do this? (When creating my Blazor app, I left out the `--no-https`)
If you're wondering which version of Blazor I'm running (WASM or Server), I don't know. I'm just following Microsoft's guide.

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set up the server to listen to other ip addresses than localhost (`127.0.0.1`). You can either give it a specific address or get it to listen to everything:

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:5000"
```